# Goland modules with private gitlab (ssh)

Tags: go, go-modules

Good day! I try to migrate from glide to go modules (private gitlab repos)
and checkout code via ssh

I have a simple project with an import from private gitlab repo.

go.mod looks like:

```
module my.private.package/modtest

go 1.12

require my.private.package/statistics v1.0.0
```

when I try to build my app or run test I get:

```
go: my.private.package/statistics@v1.0.0: unrecognized import path "my.private.package/statistics" (parse https://my.private.package/statistics?go-get=1: no go-import meta tags ())
go: error loading module requirements
```

I Tried to add settings to git config:

```
[url "ssh://git@my.gitlab.server:9999"]
        insteadOf = https://my.private.package
```

But still getting this error.

Is there any way to make it work?
Thank you.

Comment: Is your code hosting on your custom site? If so, you should have your site returns a meta tag for `go get` for your package containing repo information. See more at: https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Remote_import_paths

Comment: leaf bebop, I have a private gitlab server. HTTPS - connection is forbidden - only ssh

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that. What I ask you is to implement Go's Remote Import Protocol, which is specified by the link. The problem is not you can not get the code with git, but rather the step before it: knowing where to get the code from, which is governed by `go get`, by using Remote Import Protocol.

Answer (score 9):

I've dealt with Go modules and a private GitLab before. Our private GitLab has groups and subgroups. The piece you are likely missing is `~/.netrc` and you may have an improper global git configuration.

I've made a GitHub gist for this. You can find it here: https://gist.github.com/MicahParks/1ba2b19c39d1e5fccc3e892837b10e21

You can find the gist pasted below:

## Problem

The `go` command line tool needs to be able to fetch dependencies from your private GitLab, but authenticaiton is required.

This assumes your private GitLab is hosted at `privategitlab.company.com`.

## Environment variables

The following environment variables are recommended:

```sh
export GO111MODULE=on
export GOPRIVATE=privategitlab.company.com
```

The above lines might fit best in your shell startup, like a `~/.bashrc`.

#### Explanation

`GO111MODULE=on` tells Golang command line tools you are using modules. I have not tested this with projects not using
Golang modules on a private GitLab.

`GOPRIVATE=privategitlab.company.com` tells Golang command line tools to not use public internet resources for the hostnames
listed (like the public module proxy).

## Get a personal access token from your private GitLab

To future proof these instructions, please follow [this guide from the GitLab docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/personal_access_tokens.html#creating-a-personal-access-token).
I know that the `read_api` scope is required for Golang command line tools to work, and I may suspect `read_repository` as
well, but have not confirmed this.

## Set up the `~/.netrc`

In order for the Golang command line tools to authenticate to GitLab, a `~/.netrc` file is best to use.

To create the file if it does not exist, run the following commands:

```sh
touch ~/.netrc
chmod 600 ~/.netrc
```

Now edit the contents of the file to match the following:

```
machine privategitlab.company.com login USERNAME_HERE password TOKEN_HERE
```

Where `USERNAME_HERE` is replaced with your GitLab username and `TOKEN_HERE` is replaced with the access token aquired in the
previous section.

## Common mistakes

Do **not** set up a global git configuration with something along the lines of this:

```sh
git config --global url."git@privategitlab.company.com:".insteadOf "https://privategitlab.company.com"
```

I beleive at the time of writing this, the SSH git is not fully supported by Golang command line tools and this may cause
conflicts with the `~/.netrc`.

## Bonus: SSH config file

For regular use of the `git` tool, not the Golang command line tools, it's convient to have a `~/.ssh/config` file set up.
In order to do this, run the following commands:

```sh
mkdir ~/.ssh
chmod 700 ~/.ssh
touch ~/.ssh/config
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/config
```

Please note the permissions on the files and directory above are essentail for SSH to work in it's default configuration on
most Linux systems.

Then, edit the `~/.ssh/config` file to match the following:

```
Host privategitlab.company.com
  Hostname privategitlab.company.com
  User USERNAME_HERE
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Please note the spacing in the above file matters and will invalidate the file if it is incorrect.

Where `USERNAME_HERE` is your GitLab username and `~/.ssh/id_rsa` is the path to your SSH *private* key in your file system.
You've already uploaded its *public* key to GitLab. Here are [some instructions](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ssh/README.html#adding-an-ssh-key-to-your-gitlab-account).

Answer (score 3):

What version of Go are you using? If it's Go 1.13 or later, the default is to download modules through proxy.golang.org. You can change that for a particular set of packages using the `GOPRIVATE` environment variable.

Here is a quote from `go help module-private`, which I highly recommend reading in full. Once a module is fetched directly, it should use the same `git`/`ssh` logic as before modules.

> The GOPRIVATE environment variable controls which modules the go command
> considers to be private (not available publicly) and should therefore not use the
> proxy or checksum database. The variable is a comma-separated list of
> glob patterns (in the syntax of Go's path.Match) of module path prefixes.
> For example,
>
> GOPRIVATE=*.corp.example.com,rsc.io/private
>
> causes the go command to treat as private any module with a path prefix
> matching either pattern, including git.corp.example.com/xyzzy, rsc.io/private,
> and rsc.io/private/quux.

Comment: `go help module-private` appears to be `go help private` now